# Book for thin film interference in optics

Tags: optics, waves, resource-recommendations, interference, education

So i need to study a topic of optics which is thin film interference and i couldn't find a good book on the topic that would explain the necessary formulae derivations and contains rigorous mathematical problems. Would be really grateful if you suggest me some best books of optics containing the topic with the best interpretation of the event and step by step derivation of formula. Note that i am in the beginner stage of learning wave optics. So please recommend me books considering my level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new at this subject maybe this book called "Introduction to Optics" by Frank L. Pedrotti could be helpful.